# How to make lastname optional for custome registration and checkout

Tags: magento2

I am searching for how to make the "lastname" field optional on customer registration, edit customer, and checkout shipping, and billing address pages.

I'd like to remove server side validation too.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? In my case I'm trying to make both firstname and lastname optional.